# Visual Basic 2010 Location Property is acting strange

Tags: properties, location

I'm a bit new at programming, so apologies if this is a noob question.

I'm trying to place a button in a form, but for some reason, the button's Location Property in the form doesn't match its actual location. I tested this by making the button's text show its Location Property (in this case, "X = 10, Y = 10"), and putting this code for its click event:

```
btnTest.Text = "X = " & btnTest.Location.X & ", Y = " & btnTest.Location.Y
```

For some reason, the text now becomes "X = 8, Y = 8" The button also moves to match this new location. I don't understand why this is happening.